# Railscast doesn't recommend a solution for production, I'm looking for a reason why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, railscasts

In this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast) our good friend Mr. Bates walks through a solution to creating an app that can search, sort, and paginate a set of data.  When going through AJAX searching he provides a solution that will display results of the search the moment a user enters input into the search box.  Here is his solution:

```
$('#products_search input').keyup(function () {
  $.get($('#products_search').attr('action'), &crarr; 
    $('#products_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
  return false;
});
```

However he states "Note that this is only a quick demo and isn’t the best way to do this. There are several jQuery plugins that you can use if you do something like this in a production app."  I'm looking for an explanation on why he believes this isn't suitable for production.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues I see with this solution.  The first is that you are making an HTTP (AJAX) request every time a key is pressed, which will not be the most efficient way of doing this.  The second is that you are basically calling `eval` in the response, and `eval` is bad as it can lead to malicious users executing code you don't want to be executed.

Some suggestions on improving:

- Use a proper JSON parser and pass the data back as JSON. (you can use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))
- Throttle the request - don't do it on every keyUp, maybe start a timer and only submit the request if no keys have been pressed in the last second, meaning it won't make lots of calls for people who type fast.
- Cache the response.  If you have already searched for something, then there is no point fetching the data twice.  Keep a note (in a JS Object) of previous calls in this session and their results.